# how I can find node from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

how I can remove field tag with attribute fieldname="Age" in textarea or string value?
my textarea value is:

```
<root>
   <field displayname="سن" fieldname="Age" length="0" required="false" type="1"></field>
   <field displayname="جنسیت" fieldname="Gender" length="1" required="true" type="1"></field>
   <field displayname="شرح" fieldname="Descriptiom" length="100" required="false" type="5"></field>
</root>
```

```
var xmlString = $('#AdditionalFields').val();
var x = $(xmlString).find('[fieldname=Age]')[0];
```

I want remove x from xmlString.

Comment: The title says "how I can find node from string'. The top body asks "how I can remove field tag with attribute fieldname="Age" in textarea or string value?". The final sentence states: "I want remove x from xmlString.". Consider editing your question to clarify the problem and ask a specific question about solving that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a jQuery object from the xml, then remove the node from that object

```js
var xmlString = $('#AdditionalFields').val();

const $xml = $(xmlString);
$xml.find('[fieldname=Age]').remove();

$('#AdditionalFields').val($xml[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="AdditionalFields" cols="90" rows="10">
<root>
   <field displayname="سن" fieldname="Age" length="0" required="false" type="1"></field>
   <field displayname="جنسیت" fieldname="Gender" length="1" required="true" type="1"></field>
   <field displayname="شرح" fieldname="Descriptiom" length="100" required="false" type="5"></field>
</root>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var xmlString = `<root>
   <field displayname="سن" fieldname="Age" length="0" required="false" type="1"></field>
   <field displayname="جنسیت" fieldname="Gender" length="1" required="true" type="1"></field>
   <field displayname="شرح" fieldname="Descriptiom" length="100" required="false" type="5"></field>
</root>
`

var xmlDom = $(xmlString);
var x = xmlDom.find('[fieldname=Age]')[0];
x.remove()
console.log(xmlDom[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```